# Material ui module not found error... Module not found

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting the following material ui module not found error and can't figure out why:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Favorite' in....
```

I've installed the mui package using:

```
npm install @mui/material
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Here's the package.json file dependencies showing mui installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

In a component I have:

```
import RestoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Restore';
import FavoriteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Favorite';
import LocationOnIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocationOn';
```

and then the following rendered:

```
<BottomNavigationAction label="Recents" icon={<RestoreIcon />} />
<BottomNavigationAction label="Favorites" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
<BottomNavigationAction label="Nearby" icon={<LocationOnIcon />} />
```

this works however:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

function Demo() {
  return <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>;
}
```

Comment: The content of the `package.json` suggests that you didn't have the icon package for some reasons. Try executing `npm i @mui/icons-material` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

if you are using npm in as your package manager, or

```
yarn add @mui/icons-material
```

if you are using yarn.